# How to retrieve the div first child element sibling node using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

I have the DOM structure like below

```html
<div class="table_body">
   <div class="table_row">
      <div class="table_cell">first</div>
      <div class="table_cell">chocolate products</div><!-- want to access this div content -->
   </div>
   <div class="table_row">
      <div class="table_cell">third</div>
      <div class="table_cell">fourth</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

From the above HTML I want to access the div content of second div with classname `table_cell` inside first `table_row` div.

So basically I want to retrieve the content of div with classname `table_cell` with content chocolate products.

I have tried to do it like below

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.rdt_TableBody');
const element1 = element.querySelectorAll('.rdt_TableRow')[0]
const element2 = element1.querySelectorAll('.rdt_TableCell')[0].innerHTML;
```

When I log `element2` value it gives some strange output and not the text "chocolate products"

Could someone help me how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- the `:nth-of-type` pseudo-selector
- combined with the immediate-child selector (`>`)

---

**Example:**

```
const selectedDiv = document.querySelector('.table_body > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2)');
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const selectedDiv = document.querySelector('.table_body > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2)');

selectedDiv.style.color = 'white';
selectedDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

```html
<div class="table_body">
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_cell">first</div>
        <div class="table_cell">chocolate products</div> //want to access this div content
    </div>
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_cell">third</div>
        <div class="table_cell">fourth</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. just that to the answer i added document.querySelector

Answer (score 1):

In your code

- `element1.querySelectorAll('.table_cell')[0]`, this is targeting the first element i.e., `<div class="table_cell">first</div>`. That's the reason why you are not getting the expected output.

I have made it to `element1.querySelectorAll('.table_cell')[1]`, so that it'll target `<div class="table_cell">chocolate products</div>`.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.table_body');
const element1 = element.querySelectorAll('.table_row')[0]
const element2 = element1.querySelectorAll('.table_cell')[1].innerHTML;
console.log(element2);
```

```html
<div class="table_body">
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_cell">first</div>
    <div class="table_cell">chocolate products</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_cell">third</div>
    <div class="table_cell">fourth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since the element that you want to target is the last `div` with having class `table_cell`, you can use `:last-of-type` on `table_cell` class using `document.querySelector`. But otherwise you can also use `:nth-of-type` if there are more than 2 elements and you want to target any element in between first and last.

Below is the example using `:last-of-type`.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector(".table_row > .table_cell:last-of-type");
console.log(elem?.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="table_body">
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_cell">first</div>
    <div class="table_cell">chocolate products</div> //want to access this div content
  </div>
  <div class="table_row">
    <div class="table_cell">third</div>
    <div class="table_cell">fourth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info you can refer [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) and [`child combinator(>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Comment: and if you need 2nd `document.querySelector('div.table_row:nth-child(1) > .table_cell:nth-child(2)')`